# How to delete records with FromSqlRaw in ASP.NET Core 5?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to delete all records in a PostgresSQL database table from ASP.NET Core 5.

However, I get this error:

> syntax error at or near "FROM"

This is my code:

```
string Query = "DELETE FROM public.\"MyTable\"";
var d = await _context.MyTable.FromSqlRaw(Query).AnyAsync();
```

How to delete records with `FromSQLRaw`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DbSet<T>.FromSqlRaw` is for fetching entities with SQL.  To run an arbitrary command use [Database.ExecuteSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-5.0).  eg

```
string query = "DELETE FROM public.MyTable";
var rowCount = await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(query);
```

Comment: can the query have "Begin Transaction; DELETE from Table1; Delete From Table2; End Transaction"

Comment: So long as that's legal in your database, sure.